# create alias for network link using systemd-networkd configuration

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

I want to add aliases to my network links to use them as short descriptions. I am configuring my interfaces using systemd-networkd, having systemd version 241 on a debian buster server.

I've created the file
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68 Feb  9 12:53 /etc/systemd/network/ens19.link`
with the content:

```
[MATCH]
MACAddress=7a:08:e8:12:fc:c7

[LINK]
Alias=myalias
```

I've tried to reboot the system, but the alias does not appear:

```
3: ens19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7a:08:e8:12:fc:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Doing `ip l set ens19 alias myalias` gives the intended result:

```
3: ens19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7a:08:e8:12:fc:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    alias myalias
```

How can I achieve that using systemd-networkd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have read [the manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html) more carefully.

> The first (in lexical order) of the link files that matches a given device is applied. Note that a default file 99-default.link is shipped by the system. Any user-supplied .link should hence have a lexically earlier name to be considered at all.

Renaming `/etc/systemd/network/ens19.link` to `/etc/systemd/network/00-ens19.link` helped.

`[MATCH]` should be `[Match]` and `[LINK]` should be `[Link]`.

To apply a changed .link file to the link I can reboot or run

```
udevadm test-builtin net_setup_link /sys/class/net/ens19
```

(Because .link files are processed by udev and not systemd-networkd, restarting systemd-networkd is insufficient.)

Answer (score 0):

As per [systemd.network](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html) link aliases are not (yet?) supported.

Comment: The link alias configuration is mentioned in [systemd.link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html#Alias=)...